# Como configurar Require.JS

Tags: jquery, requirejs

Óla gente,

Estou em dúvida de configurar corretamente o `RequireJS`, como também tenho dúvidas sobre a organização de Árvores para configurar o `baseUrl` e por isso vou demonstrar como estou configurando:

```
.
├── index.html
├── js
│   ├── boot.js
│   ├── main.js
│   ├── noConflict.js
│   └── lib
│       ├── autosize.js
│       ├── drilldownmenu.js
│       ├── easing.js
│       └── smooth-scrollbar.js
└── vendor
    ├── jquery.min.js
    └── require.js
```

Está é a estrutura em Árvore do projeto e no `index.html` coloquei estas configurações:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" data-main="js/boot" src="vendor/require.js"></script>
```

Até aqui o RequireJS carrega o problema é para chamar o `jQuery`, antes vou mostrar o código da configuração `boot.js`:

```
;(function( undefined ) {
    'use strict';

    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: "./js/lib",

        paths: {
            // Módulo jQuery
            "jquery":           "../../vendor/jquery.min",
            // [Config] jQuery
            "main":             "../main"
        },

        shim: {
            "easing":           ["jquery"],
            "smooth-scrollbar": ["jquery"],
            "drilldownmenu":    ["jquery"],
            "autosize":         ["jquery"]
        },

        map: {
            "*": {
                "jquery":       "../noConflict"
            },
            "noConflict": {
                "jquery":       "jquery"
            }
        }
    });

    // Chamando módulo principal para iniciar a aplicação
    requirejs(["main"]);

})();
```

Quando eu rodo funciona até um certo ponto que é o `jQuery` que não carrega, percebam que uso uma técnica que é o `noConflict` e nele que vem o problema, ele diz que não reconhece a função `TypeError: jQuery is undefined` e quando vejo nas requisições o módulo definido no `paths` não carrega:

### [image: Requisições 200 dos arquivos sicronizados pelo RequireJS + CSS do HTML mas não carrega o jquery.min.js]

Consegui resolver o problema do `noConflict.js` usando este código no arquivo `boot.js` (Arquivo que tem às configurações do RequireJS):

```
;(function( undefined ) {
    'use strict';

    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: 'js/lib',

        paths: {
            // Módulo jQuery
            'jquery': [ '../../vendor/jquery.min',
                        '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js' ],
            // Config
            'main':             '../main'
        },

        shim: {
            'jquery':           { exports: '$' },
            'easing':           { deps: ['jquery'] },
            'smooth-scrollbar': { deps: ['jquery'] },
            'drilldownmenu':    { deps: ['jquery'] },
            'autosize':         { deps: ['jquery'] }
        },

        map: {
            '*': {
                'jquery':       '../noConflict'
            },
            '../noConflict': {
                'jquery':       'jquery'
            }
        }
    });

    // Chamando módulo principal para iniciar a aplicação
    requirejs(["main"]);

})();
```

Mas agora o `autosize.js` mostra o seguinte erro: `TypeError: $ is not a function`, sendo que o código é original sem alterações e estou usando a versão 1.18.18 no site http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

Answer (score 4, accepted):

depois de muitas tentativas consegui resolver o problema e estarei passando o tutorial para ajudar aqueles que estão iniciando configurar o RequireJS:

Antes de tudo mudei a estrutura do Projeto:

```
C:.
|   index.html
|   
+---css
|   |   color.css
|   |   grid-responsive.css
|   |   style.css
|   |   support-browser.css
|   |   
|   \---font-text
|       |   web-font.css
|       |   
|       \---iconWeb
|               
+---img
|       
+---scripts
|   |   main.js
|   |   style.js
|   |   
|   +---lib
|   |       autosize.min.js
|   |       drilldownmenu.min.js
|   |       easing.min.js
|   |       nanoscroller.min.js
|   |       smooth-scrollbar.min.js
|   |       
|   \---main
|           app.js
|           base.js
|           start.js
|           
\---vendor
        jquery.min.js
        require.min.js
```

Vamos detalhar o Funcionamento:

- **scripts:** Pasta que contém os JavaScripts para Eventos e Animações
- **scripts\lib:** São Bibliotecas de modificação
- **scripts\main:** Configurações do JavaScript
- **vendor:** Scripts de Terceiros

Agora no `index.html` devemos apontar o `RequireJS` para o `\scripts\main\app.js` que será nosso ponto de partida.

```
...
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script data-main="scripts/main/app" src="vendor/require.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Bem talvez seria bom por o `JavaScript` antes da TAG `</body>` mas percebi que nas configurações do `RequireJS` ele reescreve seu código em baixo da TAG `<link>` do `CSS` então melhor deixar de acordo que ele faz semanticamente.

Agora vamos mostrar às configurações para chamar toda a biblioteca para ser carregado de forma *assíncrona*.

```
/* ./scripts/main/app.js */
(function (undefined) {
    'use strict';
    requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: './', // Raiz
        urlArgs: function (id, url) {
            return (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'v=23';
        }, // Debug Cache
        deps: ['scripts/main/base'],
        map: {
            '*': {
                'jQuery': 'jquery'
            }
        },
        paths: {
            // Módulos
            'jquery': ['vendor/jquery.min', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min'],
            // Library jQuery
            'easing': 'scripts/lib/easing.min',
            'nanoscroller': 'scripts/lib/nanoscroller.min',
            'drilldownmenu': 'scripts/lib/drilldownmenu.min',
            'autosize': 'scripts/lib/autosize.min',
            // Config
            'start': 'scripts/main/start'
        },
        shim: {
            'easing': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'nanoscroller': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'drilldownmenu': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            },
            'autosize': {
                deps: ['jquery']
            }
        },
        waitSeconds: 15
    });
    // Chamando módulo principal para iniciar a aplicação
    require(['jquery'], function ($) {
        require(['start']);
    });
    requirejs.onError = function (err) {
        console.log(err.requireType);
        console.log('modules: ' + err.requireModules);
        throw err;
    };
})();
```

Cada item vou explicar e seus métodos para carregar às bibliotecas:

- **baseUrl:** Apontei a raiz do site ou `DocumentRoot` do projeto para o `RequireJS` começar neste ponto para por um endereçamento com a melhor visualização, para evitar o uso excessivo do `../`;
- **urlArgs:** Um método em relação ao `cache` feito pelos navegadores, que é a questão da Requisição, se por acaso for mudado algum código demorava o navegador perceber e agora se for preciso só mudar o `v=1` para outro número para atualizar às requisições;
- **deps:** excluir a referência jQuery nos caminhos RequireJS;
- **map:** no '*' significa que todos os módulos que definem o módulo especificado receberá o módulo correspondente alguns módulos e por algum motivo, alguns módulos usa require("jQuery") em vez de require("jquery");
- **paths:** neste local vamos atribuir um nome para biblioteca e seu arquivo;
- **shim:** especifica as dependências da biblioteca que não liga a `define()` ou AMD-spec compliant;
- **waitSeconds:** um tempo para verificar o código, principalmente se aplicar um `loadbalancer` que está sendo feito no `jQuery` que vai verificar se está local ou vai buscar no site oficial.

Agora vou mostrar um método baseado no https://www.caffeinecoding.com/jquery-and-amd/ em relação ao seu objeto global o `$`:

- Modificar a configuração RequireJS para calçar todos os módulos
  compatíveis não-AMD e carregar todos os plugins jQuery no início do
  carregamento da página. (Abordagem ideal)
- Importa o jQuery e todos os seus plugins fora da AMD, em seguida,
  voltar a atribuir o módulo jQuery ao global window.jQuery objeto.

Então veja o código:

```
/* ./scripts/main/base.js */
;
(function () {
    // Usando jQuery como um módulo nomeado em RequireJS
    define(['jquery'], function () {
        (function ($) {
            console.info('Verificando Global jQuery...');
            if (typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.document === 'object') {
                if (!!window && !(!!window.$)) {
                    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
                }
                console.log([$, jQuery]);
            }
            var version = $().jquery;
            if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery) {
                console.info('jQuery: ' + version + ' $.fn.jquery: ' + $.fn.jquery);
                return window.jQuery;
            }
        }(jQuery));
    });
}());
```

Agora só colocar suas configurações no `start.js`, se quiser um exemplo para iniciar:

```
/* ./scripts/main/start.js */
define(['jquery', 'easing', 'nanoscroller', 'drilldownmenu', 'autosize'], function () {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.preloader').delay(350).fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        $('body').hide(0, function () {
            $('body').delay(350).show();
        }); // Force Chrome to repaint fonts
        // Init Console
        console.log(window.console);
        if (window.console || window.console.firebug) {
            console.clear();
        }
    }); // Initialize document is ready
});
```

Veja só o resultado das requisições feito pelo `RequireJS` e sua ordem de acordo com o `start.js`:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom seu tutorial, me ajudou muito!